# How to modify user Information after requiring his password with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony5

I would like to create a page that allows the user to modify his personal infos.
I want him to enter his current password to modify any information.

I created a form based on the connected user when the form is submitted and valid, I want to check if the password is valid using the function isPasswordValid() of my passwordEncoder..

My problem is that when this function is called with $user as parameter, it always returns false. I found where this problem comes from, it's because the $user used as parameter as been modified when the form has been submitted. I've tried declaring another variable to stock my Initial User ($dbUser for example) and using another to instance the form but when I dump the
$dbUser it has been modified and I don't know why...

The variable shouldn't be changed after the submit because it's never used... I can't find what I doing wrong...

```
/**
 * @Route("/mes-infos", name="account_infos")
 */
public function showMyInfos(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepo)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

    $user = $this->getUser();
    // $dbUser = $userRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 13]);

    $form = $this->createForm(UserModificationType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $enteredPassword = $request->request->get('user_modification')['plainPassword'];
        $passwordEncoder = $this->passwordEncoder;
        $manager         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $enteredPassword)) {
            dd('it works!!!!!');
        // $manager->persist($user);
            // $manager->flush();
        } else {
            dd('It\'s not!!!!');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('account/myaccount-infos.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: _but when I dump the $dbUser it has been modified and I don't know why_. Probably because Doctrine references the same object. In some way or another when Symfony processes a HTTP request, it will fetch the user data from the database, probably using Doctrine todo so, similar how you fetch it. Doctrine is smart enough to reference both variables to the same PHP 'object'.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why `isPasswordValid` fails AFTER the `User` password property has been changed? I would expect it to work, otherwise you check a new password against the unchanged Entity user with the old password, which doesn't make sense to me. Otherwise you could use [Forms without data class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html) for all Actions that change the logged in user and update the Entity when you validated the data separately...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about how Doctrine operates because I didn't found how can my variable could be changed. 
When I talked about "$dbUser  has been modified I wanted to explain that I instance a new isolated variable like => $dbUser= $this->getUser() or with a repo request. 
Next I use a $user where I stock again the user variable to create my form etc
I used specificly this variable to create my form etc... 
But in my if->isSubmitted condition, When I tried to use the isPasswordValid($dbUser,  $passwordEntered)

Comment: This function always returns false. Howerer When I call this function outside of the ("if->isSubmitted) condition, it works, it returns true. It's with that I realized my entity $dbUser where changed and was not anymore the user in my database. The object contains modified information of the form submit.

Comment: Maybe i have a wrong idea of what `isPasswordValid ` does. In this case i would use Xdebug and go through every level until i see where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use a constraint.

Symfony already implements a [UserPasswordConstraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html).

You can add it in your entity directly. Be careful to declare [a group for this constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html). If you don't do it, your use case "user update" will works fine, but the use case "user creation" will now failed.

```php
    namespace App\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints as SecurityAssert;

    class User
    {
        //...
        /**
         * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
         *     message = "Wrong value for your current password",
         *     groups = {"update"}
         * )
         */
        protected $password;
        //...
    }
```

In your form, specified the [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html) by updating (or adding) the configureOptions method:

```php
//App\Form\UserModificationType
//...
class UserModificationType {

    //...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // ...
            'validation_groups' => ['update'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then your $form->isValid() will automatically test the password. So, you can removed all lines in the "if condition".

```php
   /**
     * @Route("/mes-infos", name="account_infos")
     */
    public function showMyInfos(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepo)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(UserModificationType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dd('Password is good! it works!!!!!');
        }

        return $this->render('account/myaccount-infos.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

But I think it is **a better practice** to use a Model like [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html) when you update your user entity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211432/discussion-on-answer-by-alexandre-tranchant-how-to-modify-user-information-after).